# FLAC or OGG Online Media player

Tags: java, audio, streaming, codec, ogg

Is there a way to make an audio/video player in Java that can play on a website?

I searched around but I don't understand enough yet for this.

We are going to setup a server that can stream OGG and FLAC audio files. We need a player that can play them on a webpage.

Our backend is built with Java. Before we put together a project for a Java programmer I want to know what the possibilities are.

Can this be done with an applet and simply add the right codecs and place it on the webpage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found [jPlayer](http://jplayer.org). HTML5 with flash fallback.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, we made js flac player. This is code of js codec: https://github.com/audiocogs/flac.js
This framework https://github.com/audiocogs/aurora.js for made player

Answer (score 0):

You just to embed the HTML for a player, then add your own script to play the audio/video.

Here's how to Embed the code for WMP:
`http://www.mioplanet.com/rsc/embed_mediaplayer.htm`

Sorry, I don't know what files it can play but just give it a shot...

Comment: Thanks. We have a requirement that we can't rely on the client having certain programs installed, besides maybe flash, but flash can't handle OGG or FLAC. We need to have control over the design as well. Also, by default WMP can't play FLAC or OGG.

Comment: Maybe you can use the HTML5 `<video>` tag. Tell me if you need info on it, I'll be glad to help you.

Comment: Great suggestion, thanks! However, we have to support IE8 and IE7 :( I would give my right leg to use HTML5 for it, but I don't think Microsoft would take my offering in exchange for them to update deprecated browsers to HTML5...